# Python read multiple pickled dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, input, io, pickle

I have 261 pickled dictionary objects ( `task_0.pkl, task_1.pkl ,...`)

I want read them. I have tried

```
c=[]
for i in range(261):
    with open('result_20140213/task_%i.pkl' %i , 'rb') as handle:
        c.append(pickle.load(handle))
```

It gives

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
EOFError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-a5aa784bbbb0> in <module>()
      2 for i in range(261):
      3     with open('result_20140213/task_%i.pkl' %i , 'rb') as handle:
----> 4         c.append(pickle.load(handle))

EOFError: Ran out of input
```

Further I tried:

```
for i in range(261):
    with open('result_20140213/task_%i.pkl' %i , 'rb') as handle:
        pickle.load(handle)
```

It also gives

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
EOFError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-660cce2aef10> in <module>()
      2 for i in range(261):
      3     with open('result_20140213/task_%i.pkl' %i , 'rb') as handle:
----> 4         pickle.load(handle)

EOFError: Ran out of input
```

It seems with open can not be used here.

How could I read these pickled dictionaries?

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue but in the first line of your question you indicated that the task ids start at `1` while your loop index starts at `0`.

Comment: Seems that the problem is not with your code, but rather with the contents of the files. You can try printing `i` on every loop iteration to find out which file is the problematic one.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the file is empty.

```
    import os
    import io
    for i in range(261):
        with io.TextIOWrapper(open('result_20140213/task_%i.pkl' %i, 'rb')) as handle:
            if os.stat('result_20140213/task_%i.pkl' %i).st_size == 0:
                pickle.load(handle)
```

`

Answer (score 0):

range(261) yields 0,1,...,260.

Do you have a task_0.pkl?

maybe you meant range(1,262)?

Comment: I have a task_0.pkl

Answer (score 0):

I know why.... I put `'wb'`

```
for i in range(261):
    with open('result_20140213/task_%i.pkl' %i , 'rb') as handle:
        pickle.load(handle)
```

So it will firstly create empty files..... Thanks everyone.